# MP3 stream won't play with HTML5 Audio in Chrome

Tags: audio-streaming, html5-audio

I'm currently debugging why this MP3 stream doesn't play in Chrome.

I have the following code:
http://jsfiddle.net/6XVQB/

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="http://radio.4play.fm:80/192.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

This works fine in firefox but not in Chrome. The stream is being delivered using Icecast. When I serve the same stream using Shoutcast at http://radio.4play.fm:443/192.mp3 it works fine in Chrome.

Comment: What if you use `audio/mp3` as your mime-type, does that work?

Comment: audio/mp3 doesn't work either.

Comment: @SeanBannister No issues here with that stream in Chrome in your JSFiddle.  Perhaps the server was having difficulties while you were testing?

Comment: @Brad that's interesting I'll check on a few more computer as I'm still experiencing this issue.

Comment: @SeanBannister What OS?

Comment: this might be of some help - https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/play-returns-promise?hl=en

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes streaming radio stations try to mislead or spoof the identity of their streams.

I just developed an HTML5 radio jukebox http://m.gooplusplus.com/?radio

In the process, I found that I often had to "tweak" the URL to make things work.

Try this alternate code for your stream:

`<audio controls src="http://radio.4play.fm:80/192.mp3#.m4a" type="audio/mpeg">`

BTW, I added the 80kbps Ogg version of your stream to my site (E2) since I know little about electronica/club music and need a few more stations in that genre.

Comment: Adding an anchor fragment to an audio resource like this does absolutely nothing unless you have some very broken code looking at "file name extension" instead of the proper `Content-Type` headers, in which case your player software will fail on most internet radio servers out there.

Comment: It's definitely appears to be an issue with the filname extension, because our alternative URL http://radio.4play.fm:80/mp3 works fine. However this isn't an issue with broken code on our end it appears to be an issue with Chrome as we're just using the raw <audio> element.

Comment: @SeanBannister It has nothing to do with filename extension, I promise you.  Your alternative URL is a completely different resource.  It's a different stream entirely.

Comment: Brad is much more knowledgeable about this streaming stuff but I just know what worked and what did not. In a bare HTML page, `<audio controls src="http://radio.4play.fm:80/192.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">` does not work. `src="http://radio.4play.fm:80/192.m4a` also does not work. However, for whatever reason, `<audio controls src="http://radio.4play.fm:80/192.mp3#.m4a" type="audio/mpeg">` works in Google Chrome.

Comment: @Brad In Icecast (the server I'm using to stream) the /mp3 URL is simply an alias of /192.mp3 which I setup for simplicity, the streams are exactly the same as far as audio and headers go.